# How to detect which program is consuming memory using $ps aux

Tags: 16.04, memory-usage

Recently my Ubuntu 16.04 is slowing down and often freezes while using Chrome, VLC player, Atom editor etc. I need to find out which program is consuming my memory. Since I am new to Linux, I don't know how to detect and take steps to reduce memory consumption.

```
prefix_108@prefix108-X510UQ:~$ ps -aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  0.0 185624  6152 ?        Ss   12:17   0:01 /sbin/init splash
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         8  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:01 [rcu_sched]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [migration/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [cpuhp/1]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [migration/1]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [cpuhp/2]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [watchdog/2]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [migration/2]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [cpuhp/3]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [watchdog/3]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [migration/3]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kworker/3:0]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/3:0H]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [netns]
root        35  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:02 [kworker/2:1]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [oom_reaper]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [writeback]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kcompactd0]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   12:17   0:00 [ksmd]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   12:17   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [crypto]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kblockd]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [md]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [edac-poller]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [watchdogd]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kworker/u8:1]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kauditd]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        97  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root       104  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root       129  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [charger_manager]
root       175  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       176  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root       177  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       178  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root       180  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [nvkm-disp]
root       181  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:01 [i915/signal:0]
root       182  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [i915/signal:1]
root       183  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [i915/signal:2]
root       184  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [i915/signal:4]
root       185  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kworker/u8:3]
root       187  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/3:1H]
root       188  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root       190  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root       191  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/2:1H]
root       192  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       214  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [jbd2/sda9-8]
root       215  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       245  0.0  0.0  35404  5092 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       260  0.5  0.0  46768  5592 ?        Ss   12:17   0:05 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       261  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kworker/1:2]
root       271  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:01 [kworker/3:3]
root       298  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [kworker/u8:4]
root       376  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [asus_wireless_w]
root       377  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [loop0]
root       383  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [loop1]
root       384  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [loop2]
root       416  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [irq/128-mei_me]
root       421  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [irq/109-ELAN130]
root       440  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [cfg80211]
root       484  0.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:08 [irq/129-iwlwifi]
root       485  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/u9:0]
systemd+   491  0.0  0.0 102384  2580 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root       499  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [kworker/u9:1]
root       509  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:17   0:00 [led_workqueue]
root       628  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:17   0:00 [spi32766]
root       979  0.0  0.0   4396  1316 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root       981  0.0  0.0  28660  3200 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root       985  0.0  0.1 298816  8612 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
avahi     1041  0.0  0.0  44920  3240 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [prefix108-X510UQ.local]
root      1046  0.0  0.1 173808  9104 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable
root      1084  0.0  0.0  36404  3312 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
message+  1085  0.1  0.0  44464  5472 ?        Ss   12:17   0:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-a
root      1110  0.0  0.0  32092  4208 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
root      1114  0.0  0.0 236260  2864 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/bin/lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs/
root      1118  0.0  0.2 389904 18204 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
syslog    1122  0.0  0.0 256392  3440 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      1127  0.0  0.3 308600 27196 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
root      1212  0.0  0.0  19600   264 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid
avahi     1247  0.0  0.0  44788   336 ?        S    12:17   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root      1274  0.0  0.1 292200  8092 ?        SLsl 12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
root      1339  9.7  1.5 460972 123992 tty7    Ssl+ 12:17   1:29 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten 
colord    1377  0.0  0.1 320980 12896 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/lib/colord/colord
root      1409  0.0  0.1 304832 11048 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root      1528  0.0  0.0  44032  7080 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
whoopsie  1555  0.0  0.1 378512 12800 ?        Ssl  12:17   0:00 /usr/bin/whoopsie -f
root      1582  0.0  0.0  23328  1760 tty1     Ss+  12:17   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
lxc-dns+  1714  0.0  0.0  60260   408 ?        S    12:17   0:00 dnsmasq -u lxc-dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/lxc/dnsma
root      1763  0.0  0.4 370128 32652 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data  1765  0.0  0.1 370128  8168 ?        S    12:17   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1766  0.0  0.1 370128  8168 ?        S    12:17   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root      1875  0.0  0.0  28568  3720 ?        S    12:17   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql     2042  0.1  0.7 626784 62512 ?        Sl   12:17   0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/my
root      2043  0.0  0.0  33484  1424 ?        S    12:17   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon error
root      2053  0.0  0.4 402128 34520 ?        Ss   12:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      2312  0.0  0.0 232384  6260 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 lightdm --session-child 12 19
rtkit     2372  0.0  0.0 183548  2916 ?        SNsl 12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
root      2392  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:18   0:00 [krfcommd]
prefix_+  2468  0.0  0.0  45388  5260 ?        Ss   12:18   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
prefix_+  2469  0.0  0.0 147708  2344 ?        S    12:18   0:00 (sd-pam)
prefix_+  2502  0.0  0.1 213456  8052 ?        SLl  12:18   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
root      2505  0.0  0.0  16124  3664 ?        S    12:18   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhcl
prefix_+  2507  0.0  0.0  53876  4984 ?        Ss   12:18   0:00 /sbin/upstart --user
nobody    2526  0.0  0.0  60260  4240 ?        S    12:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces -
prefix_+  2710  0.0  0.0  40256   280 ?        S    12:18   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon --user
prefix_+  2711  0.4  0.0  44176  4724 ?        Ss   12:18   0:03 dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-tS2fCdU54A
prefix_+  2723  0.0  0.1  93752  8936 ?        Ss   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/window-stack-bridge
prefix_+  2743  0.4  0.1 439996  9176 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:04 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim --address unix:tmpdir=/tmp/ibus
prefix_+  2761  0.0  0.0 281912  6616 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
prefix_+  2766  0.0  0.0 419968  7044 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
prefix_+  2775  0.0  0.1 284968  8244 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-dconf
prefix_+  2779  0.0  0.0  40188   300 ?        S    12:18   0:00 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-name system
prefix_+  2781  0.1  0.0  40260  1752 ?        S    12:18   0:01 upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --session --user --bus-name session
prefix_+  2785  0.0  0.0  48680   388 ?        S    12:18   0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon --user
prefix_+  2788  0.1  0.4 493508 32840 ?        Sl   12:18   0:01 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-ui-gtk3
prefix_+  2792  0.0  0.3 443548 24176 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
prefix_+  2801  0.0  0.1 353876  8104 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
prefix_+  2806  0.0  0.0  43028  4080 ?        S    12:18   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --pri
prefix_+  2808  0.0  0.0 206868  4972 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
prefix_+  2819  0.2  0.4 543376 33664 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:02 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon
prefix_+  2824  0.0  0.0 173928   712 ?        Ss   12:18   0:00 gpg-agent --homedir /home/prefix_108/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
prefix_+  2834  0.6  0.6 742728 50972 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:05 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
prefix_+  2836  0.0  0.4 944428 35960 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon
prefix_+  2850  0.0  0.1 573328 15652 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
root      2856  0.0  0.1 355096 10612 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
prefix_+  2896  0.7  0.5 662624 45404 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:06 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity/unity-panel-service
prefix_+  2900  0.1  0.0 209084  7884 ?        Sl   12:18   0:01 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
prefix_+  2929  0.0  0.0 178924  4904 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
prefix_+  2941  0.0  0.0  22368  1116 ?        S    12:18   0:00 syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
prefix_+  2946  1.8  0.1 442624 12436 ?        S<l  12:18   0:16 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
prefix_+  2970  0.0  0.1 377576  9524 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
prefix_+  2971  0.0  0.0 356640  8024 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service
prefix_+  2972  0.0  0.1 368856 11896 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
prefix_+  2975  0.0  0.2 1247148 17192 ?       Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
prefix_+  2976  0.0  0.3 729680 26840 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-keyboard/indicator-keyboard-service --use-gtk
prefix_+  2978  0.1  0.1 683724 13352 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:01 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
prefix_+  2979  0.0  0.3 562764 25936 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-printers/indicator-printers-service
prefix_+  2988  0.0  0.1 840388  8564 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-session/indicator-session-service
prefix_+  3030  0.1  0.1 407540 13180 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:01 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
prefix_+  3055  0.0  0.2 642408 23784 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
prefix_+  3079  0.0  0.2 444760 22404 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
prefix_+  3083  2.4  1.0 1494080 84232 ?       Sl   12:18   0:21 nautilus -n
prefix_+  3084  0.0  0.4 605140 35768 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 nm-applet
prefix_+  3085  0.1  0.9 753444 77676 ?        SLl  12:18   0:01 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
prefix_+  3104  0.2  0.3 526484 25628 ?        Sl   12:18   0:02 /usr/bin/indicator-netspeed
prefix_+  3105  0.0  0.5 564816 41552 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/indicator-stickynotes
prefix_+  3106  0.0  0.2 590096 23392 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-fallback-mount-helper
prefix_+  3117  0.4  0.6 893700 56216 ?        Sl   12:18   0:03 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/safeeyes
prefix_+  3122  0.5  1.6 3543708 132600 ?      SLl  12:18   0:04 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --executed-from=/home/prefix_108 --pid=311
prefix_+  3127 18.6  1.7 2714904 144372 ?      Ssl  12:18   2:40 compiz
prefix_+  3130  0.0  0.3 101428060 31560 ?     Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
prefix_+  3138  0.0  0.1 377516  9900 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
root      3158  0.0  0.1 382548 10172 ?        Ssl  12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd --no-debug
prefix_+  3184  0.0  0.0 279116  6080 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
prefix_+  3192  0.0  0.0 266920  4512 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
prefix_+  3199  0.0  0.7 881440 60556 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
prefix_+  3214  0.0  0.1 411000  9052 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
prefix_+  3220  0.0  0.0 264928  5532 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
prefix_+  3250  0.0  0.6 895684 51084 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory contacts --bus
prefix_+  3254  0.0  0.1 296348  8768 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-identity-service
prefix_+  3263  0.0  0.1 392032 12468 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
prefix_+  3271  0.0  0.2 704756 19680 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory
prefix_+  3273  0.0  0.6 880064 50528 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory local --bus-na
prefix_+  3298  0.0  0.2 780228 19040 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess --factory local --bus
prefix_+  3321  0.0  0.1 371308  8992 ?        Sl   12:18   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.4 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
prefix_+  3335  0.0  0.5 383864 41148 ?        S    12:18   0:00 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=zygote --no-sandbox
prefix_+  3369  0.0  0.0  68696  5304 ?        S    12:19   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
prefix_+  3419  0.0  1.0 816140 86516 ?        Sl   12:19   0:00 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=gpu-process --no-sandbox --supports
prefix_+  3467  0.9  2.9 3536624 241376 ?      Sl   12:19   0:07 /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --type=renderer --ms-disable-indexeddb-tra
prefix_+  4411  0.1  0.2 593696 17476 ?        Sl   12:19   0:01 zeitgeist-datahub
prefix_+  4418  0.0  0.0   4504   808 ?        S    12:19   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-maybe-vacuum; /usr/bin/z
prefix_+  4422  0.0  0.1 423716  9532 ?        Sl   12:19   0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
prefix_+  4564  0.0  0.8 372780 67252 ?        Sl   12:19   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist-fts
prefix_+  5284  0.0  0.4 502508 32776 ?        Sl   12:19   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
prefix_+  5434  0.0  0.3 537136 27460 ?        Sl   12:19   0:00 update-notifier
prefix_+  5671  0.0  0.1 371560  8708 ?        Sl   12:20   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-network --spawner :1.4 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
root      5710  0.0  0.0  19940  2572 ?        Ss   12:20   0:00 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sda6 /media/prefix_108/Programming -o rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1
prefix_+  5739  0.0  0.0 193336  4424 ?        Sl   12:20   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
prefix_+  5744  0.0  0.1 448768  8784 ?        Sl   12:20   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
prefix_+  5774  0.0  0.0 369108  6852 ?        Sl   12:20   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-dnssd --spawner :1.4 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/11
root      6097  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:22   0:00 [kworker/2:0]
root      6098  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:22   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
prefix_+  6117  0.0  0.2 720132 17592 ?        Sl   12:22   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-scope-home/unity-scope-home
prefix_+  6149  0.0  0.2 584852 23916 ?        Sl   12:22   0:00 /usr/bin/unity-scope-loader applications/applications.scope applications/scopes.s
prefix_+  6151  0.0  0.1 523536 14040 ?        Sl   12:22   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-lens-files/unity-files-daemon
prefix_+  6153  0.0  0.1 345360 15044 ?        Sl   12:22   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity-lens-music/unity-music-daemon
www-data  6588  0.0  0.1 402160  9808 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6589  0.0  0.1 402160  9808 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6590  0.0  0.1 402160  9808 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6591  0.0  0.1 402160  9808 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6592  0.0  0.1 402160  9808 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      6642  0.0  0.0 100860  7724 ?        Ss   12:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
root      6644  0.0  0.1 274956  9612 ?        Ssl  12:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
lp        6669  0.0  0.0  81248  5728 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6672  0.0  0.0  81248  5584 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6673  0.0  0.0  81248  5752 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6674  0.0  0.0  81248  5592 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6675  0.0  0.0  81248  5556 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6676  0.0  0.0  81248  5672 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6677  0.0  0.0  81248  5684 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6678  0.0  0.0  81248  5740 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6679  0.0  0.0  81248  5604 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
lp        6680  0.0  0.0  81248  5632 ?        S    12:23   0:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
root      6939  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:26   0:00 [kworker/3:2]
prefix_+  6966  7.9  2.0 1024096 168212 ?      SLl  12:26   0:32 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
prefix_+  6973  0.0  0.0  14836   668 ?        S    12:26   0:00 cat
prefix_+  6974  0.0  0.0  14836   820 ?        S    12:26   0:00 cat
prefix_+  6977  0.0  0.6 431280 56076 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=e794b0a6-cf68-4f3
prefix_+  6978  0.0  0.0  23772  4000 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
prefix_+  6981  0.0  0.1 431280 13692 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=e794b0a6-cf68-4f3
prefix_+  7040  4.8  1.5 568160 121528 ?       Sl   12:26   0:19 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=357899629384001
prefix_+  7045  0.0  0.1 459536 14140 ?        S    12:26   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=-broker
root      7186  0.0  0.0  20064  2648 ?        Ss   12:26   0:00 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sda3 /media/prefix_108/Docs -o rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid
root      7197  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:26   0:00 [kworker/u8:0]
prefix_+  7242 19.3  2.3 1229352 190844 ?      Sl   12:27   1:04 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=357899629384001314
prefix_+  7273 30.0  1.9 2090444 153224 ?      Sl   12:27   1:37 /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file /home/prefix_108/Videos/O Fly On - Coldplay.mp4
root      7304  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:27   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root      7312  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:27   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root      7546  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:31   0:00 [kworker/2:2]
prefix_+  7620  4.0  0.4 652368 39448 ?        Sl   12:32   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
prefix_+  7627  0.1  0.0  30056  5504 pts/4    Ss   12:32   0:00 bash
root      7647  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:32   0:00 [kworker/1:1]
prefix_+  7660  0.0  0.0  44760  3444 pts/4    R+   12:33   0:00 ps -aux
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use htop you can then select to order the processes by Memory consumption and see which processes are problematics. Just type

```
htop
```

in your command line and then click on CPU%.